# I want to take my current list of tuples and put them in a two-column format BUT have the first line as a header

Tags: python, tuples

I have this code going through my original file, reading and creating the list of tuples.

```
def initialize_portfolio(filename):

    port_list = []
    with open("holdings.txt") as filename:
        for line in filename:
            # strip removes all leading and trailing spaces
            line = line.strip()
            # skip empty lines
            if not line:
                continue
            # use partition to split the entries
            a, _, b = line.partition(',')
            a = a.strip()
            b = int(b.strip())
            # create a tuple while appending
            port_list.append((a, b))

    return port_list
```

and I want to take that list and use the function def print_portfolio, to print the list that I made above into a two column format, including the first line header.

```
Symbol         Amount
BB             1000
TIS         8574
LIG         1333
etc...         etc...
etc...
```

portfolio = the list of tuples I created in the first function

I want the function to be

```
def print_portfolio(portfolio):
```

Just to organize the tuple in two columns

Please no dictionaries

Comment: What's the problem? Just use a `for` loop to iterate over the list and print the two tuple elements.

Comment: Hey @Barmar I want to print it in a way that formats it as two columns with a header

Comment: Print the header first, then loop and print the rows.

Comment: `print(x[0], x[1])` will print a tuple `x` in two columns.

Comment: How do I get the list that's formatted like this [(BB, 1000), (TIS, 8574) etc...] to print into two columns?

Comment: With a loop: `for x in portfolio:`

Comment: Or `for symbol, amount  in portfolio:`

Comment: I'm not getting the headers to show before the columns

Comment: `print("Symbol Amount")`

Comment: This is less complicated than the function you wrote to read from the file, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: How would I take the sum of everything in just the Amount column?

Comment: `sum(amt for symbol, amt in portfolio)`

Comment: Why did you remove what you want to do from the question? It makes absolutely no sense any more.

Comment: Honestly I was trying to upload a new question and then realized i edit this one and dont rem. how to change it back

Comment: Click on the "edited at ..." link to see the history, find the old version and click on "rollback".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the header, then loop through the portfolio printing each line.

```
def print_portfolio(portfolio):
    print("Symbol Amount")
    for symbol, amt in portfolio:
        print(symbol, amt)
```

If you want the columns to line up, use a formatting method to specify the column widths:

```
def print_portfolio(portfolio):
    print("Symbol Amount")
    for symbol, amt in portfolio:
        print(f"{symbol:6} {amt:6}")
```